# The sequence $n^2+1$ and semiprimes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Does the set $ \{n^2+1 : n \in \mathbb N\}$ contain infinitely many semiprimes?

Also, are there any results on density of semiprimes in this sequence?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151159/status-of-the-x2-1-problem

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi Thank you. Do you know are there any results on density of semiprimes in this sequence?

Comment: @Farewell I've included the follow-up about density on the original question, otherwise it is a duplicate. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Myshkin Nicely done.

Answer (score 5):

Iwaniec's original proof is avaible online

- Henryk Iwaniec, "[Almost-Primes Represented by Quadratic Polynomials](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/download/PPN356556735_0047/PPN356556735_0047___LOG_0016.pdf)" (1978)

In the same paper he also proves the following lower bound for the density of semiprimes in this sequence, for sufficiently large $x$:

$$\frac{1}{154}\prod \left( 1-\frac{\rho(p)}{p} \right)\left( 1-\frac{1}{p} \right)^{-1}\frac{x}{\log x}$$

where $\rho(p)$ is the number of solutions of $n^2+1\equiv 0\,\mathrm{mod}\, p$.

Answer (score 4):

See [OEIS sequence A144255](https://oeis.org/A144255).  This refers to 
Iwaniec, H., "Almost primes represented by quadratic polynomials", Invent. math. 47, 1978, 171-188, with the comment

> Iwaniec proves that there are an infinite number of semiprimes or primes of the form n^2+1.